# ms access auto number doesn't update correctly when running append query

Tags: ms-access

I have a temp table that I need to append to my main table (TblField)

TblField has a primary Key of FIELDID - which is autonumber.

When I append to TBLFIELD - the autoumber doesnt update with the latest number but rather starts at number 1.

My SQL looks as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TblField (BusinessAreaID, DomainCatID, BusinessTermID, BusinessOwner, BusinessSME, BusinessTermLong, [TableID], GTS_BusinessName, GTS_Description, DataType2, OriginID, FieldName, Business_Rules, DataCategory)
SELECT TempTable.BusinessAreaID,
       TempTable.SubDomainID,
       TempTable.[Business Term ],
       TempTable.[Business Owner ],
       TempTable.[Business SME ],
       TempTable.[Business Term Long Description ],
       TempTable.PhysTableID,
       TempTable.[Source Table Business Name (GTS/RDM/MDM Only)],
       TempTable.[Source Table Definition (GTS/RDM/MDM Only)],
       TempTable.[Data Type ],
       TempTable.OriginID,
       TempTable.[Field name ],
       TempTable.[Business Rules],
       TempTable.[Data Category e#g# Master Data]
FROM TempTable
WHERE (((TempTable.fieldID)=0));
```

[image]
My data then comes out as attached image - where the test data is actually the new records.

This causes a key violoation.

I have compressed my database.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you filter on _FieldID=0_, your posted output must come from another query.

Comment: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-40.html might help.

Comment: I had this happen years ago in an older version of access (Maybe 2000?)  When the office people would post the day's transactions, it would take the transactions from one table and append them to another (one in which the PK was an autonumber).  Literally worked for years.  And then one day it started trying to begin the autonumbering of the appended records--not at zero like yours--but anywhere that it found a gap.  For instance, if previously deleted records caused a gap at 1103, it would attempt to start the numbering at 1103.  Key violations would cause the code to dump and only *some* of

Comment: the transactions were posted.  Accounts got *seriously* jacked up before I realized what was going on.  I eventually had to change the autonumber field to an integer and have it manually calculate the next available number on every append.  Took longer for the queries to run, but no more key violations.  Weird bug.  Never did figure it out...